# How to get invoked handleInterruptPacket override method in case of ACM DEXT(IOUserUSBSerial)?

Tags: macos, driverkit, macos-system-extension

In ACM Dext **handleInterruptPacket** override method is not getting invoked by the system. Kindly let me know anything missing.

iig file:

```
class UserUsbACMControl: public IOUserUSBSerial
{
    virtual void
    handleInterruptPacket(const uint8_t *packet, uint32_t size) override;
}
```

cpp file:

```
void UserUsbACMControl::handleInterruptPacket(const uint8_t *packet, uint32_t size)
{

}
```

But if AsyncIO request sent to Interrupt EP able to get response AsyncIO completion(CompleteAsyncIO). Please check [How to access the IOMemoryBufferDescriptor in CompleteAsyncIO, which is sent through AsyncIO on Interrupt EP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62476424/how-to-access-the-iomemorybufferdescriptor-in-completeasyncio-which-is-sent-thr)